# Read XML tags and then remove XML tags using a shell script

Tags: unix, shell-script, sed, awk

Given the following input:

```
<start>
   <header>
      This is header section
   </header>
   <body>
      <body_start>
         This is body section
         <a>
            <b>
               <c>
                  <st>111</st>
               </c>
               <d>
                  <st>blank</st>
               </d>
            </b>
         </a>
      </body_start>
      <body_section>
         This is body section
         <a>
            <b>
               <c>
                  <st>5</st>
               </c>
               <d>
                  <st>666</st>
               </d>
            </b>
            <b>
               <c>
                  <st>154</st>
               </c>
               <d>
                  <st>1457954</st>
               </d>
            </b>
            <b>
               <c>
                  <st>845034</st>
               </c>
               <d>
                  <st>blank</st>
               </d>
            </b>
         </a>
      </body_section>
   </body>
</start>
```

I'd like to perform the following parsing.

If `st` value of `c` tag is `154`, then the whole `<b>` to `</b>` tag needs to removed. Note that value 154 may or not be present in the file.

So, if the value 154 is present, then the removal of the following part is needed:

```
<b>
   <c>
      <st>154</st>
   </c>
   <d>
      <st>1457954</st>
   </d>
</b>
```

I want to do the coding in a shell script. I can not use `xslt` because my system does not support it.

Comment: I think `sed` isn't the ideal tool for this task. You should use perl, php or similar language - or a xml-releated tool.

Comment: Why inventing a bicycle if nearly all unix based system has in their repos `xmlstarlet` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pup`](https://github.com/EricChiang/pup), a command line tool for processing HTML. For XML you can use [`xpup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/xpup).

For example, to find parts for removal, run:

```
$ pup ':parent-of(:parent-of(:contains("154")))' <file.html
<b>
 <c>
  <st>
   154
  </st>
 </c>
 <d>
  <st>
   1457954
  </st>
 </d>
</b>
```

To remove this section from the input using `sed` (where `file.html` is your HTML file), run:

```
 sed "s@$(pup ':parent-of(:parent-of(:contains("154")))' <file.html | xargs | tr -d " ")@@g" <(xargs <file.html | tr -d " ")
```

Notes:

- We use `xargs <file.html | tr -d " "` to flatten the file into a single line without spaces.
- We use mentioned `pup` command to find the pattern for removal.
- We use `sed` to remove the pattern by: `sed "s@PATTERN@@g" <(input)`.
- To replace in-place (by modifying the file), add `-i` for GNU's `sed`, or `-i'.bak'` for BSD's `sed`.

---

For easier understanding, the following script can be used:

```
function flat_it() { xargs | tr -d " "; }
input=$(flat_it <file.html)
remove=$(pup ':parent-of(:parent-of(:contains("154")))' <<<$input | flat_it)
sed "s@$remove@@g" <<<$input
```

---

Note: The disadvantage of the above method is that all spaces are removed, including in the content. To make it better, some other way of flattening input needs to be used.

So instead of `xargs | tr -d " "`, `sed`, `ex` or `paste` can be used.

Here is the example using `ex`:

```
ex +%j +"s/[><]\zs //g" +%p -scq! file.html
```

And here is the version with shell function (which can replace the previous version):

```
function flat_it() { ex +%j +"s/[><]\zs //g" +%p -scq! /dev/stdin; }
```